Reflection $\sigma_{e^{\prime}}(rcos(\theta),rsen(\theta),\tilde{x})=(rcos(2\theta_{0}-\theta + \pi),rsen(2\theta_0-\theta + \pi),\tilde{x})$
My question comes from the academic paper: Symmetry of solutions to semilinear elliptic equations via Morse Index. The author is Filomena Pacella.
Let $S$ be the vector of the $n$-dimensional unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : |x|=1\}$. For a unit vector $e \in S$, we consider the hyperplane $H(e)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N : x\cdot e=0 \}$ and the open half-domain of the $n$-sphere $B(e)=\{ x\in B\ : x\cdot e > 0 \}$. We define $\sigma_{e} : B \rightarrow B$ as the reflection with respect to $H(e)$, that is, $\sigma_{e}(x)=x-2(x\cdot e)e$  for each $x \in B$.
Since $\sigma_{e}(x)$ is a reflection, the following properties hold
\begin{equation*}
    H(-e)=H(e) \quad \text{y} \quad B(-e)=\sigma_{e}(B(e))=-B(e) \quad \text{para cada} \; e\in S
  \end{equation*}
A new vector $e^{\prime}=(\cos(\theta_{0}), \sin(\theta_{0}), 0, \ldots, 0)$ is defined for some $\theta_{0} \in \left(- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Since only the first two coordinates are modified, the remaining coordinates are grouped into $\tilde{x}=(x_3, \ldots, x_N)$. We convert to cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates for the first two, $x_1= r \cos(\theta)$, $x_2= r \sin(\theta)$.
We use the reflection with vector $e^{\prime}$ over the hyperplane $H(e^{\prime})$, so we name it $\sigma_{e^{\prime}}(x)$. The coordinates of the image after applying the reflection are
\begin{equation*}
   \sigma_{e^{\prime}}(rcos(\theta),rsen(\theta),\tilde{x})=(rcos(2\theta_{0}-\theta + \pi),rsen(2\theta_0-\theta + \pi),\tilde{x})
  \end{equation*}
Do you know how it arrived at the expression $2\theta_{0} - \theta + \pi$? Is any trigonometric property being used here?
One more thing, could someone share a link with a diagram explaining this application?
Linear transformations that are reflections are usually defined with matrices and those that are not defined this way are not similar to this one.

See the diagram below, representing the $x_1x_2$ plane. If $\theta$ is the polar angle of point $P$, you can check that the polar angle of its reflection $P'$ is
$$
2\left({\pi\over2}+\theta_0-\theta\right)+\theta=\pi+2\theta_0-\theta.
$$


Ok, now I get it. You know that the plane and the vector $e^{\prime}$ are perpendicular so the angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then you have $\frac{\pi}{2}+ \theta_{0}$. If you choose an arbitrary angle $\theta$ between $\frac{\pi}{2}+ \theta_{0}$ and $\theta_{0}$ when $\theta$ rests on $\frac{\pi} {2}+ \theta_{0}$ you will get the desired angle. Since you apply a reflection, that angle is the same on each side. Thanks you @Intelligentipauca
